# How to call a function whenever new li is added to ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-lists

Here is ul where new li will be dropped:

```
 <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default li-cat">Appetizers</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default li-cat">Soups</li>
  </ul>
```

Here is ul from where ul will be dragged:

```
 <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default ap dd">Cobb Salad</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default soup dd">Gazpacho</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default salad dd">Prime Rib</li>
 </ul>
```

jqueryui function to connect both list:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

I simply want to call a javascript function whenever a new element(li) is added to ul. Am using jqueryui sortable for drag and drop.

Comment: Can you share your javascript code?

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant source code please? How/where is the new `li` element created? Thank you.

Comment: So use `drop` event. http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: Thanks! And does .selector class in that function correspond to my .connectedSortable class?

Comment: Yes. Take a look: http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-ui/sortable-connectwith.html

Comment: which function you want to call when li is added and also where is the new li element created in draggable or droppable?

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed Thanks!  I needed to call some other things to trigger when item is dragged @RajenRanjith

Comment: ok.......i want to know in which ul (i.e draggable or droppable) you want to add li...........

Answer (score 0):

```
use change property in jquery sortable, so whenever sortable list is changing this change property will trigger automatically.....
```

```
 (function($) {
   var beforeChangeUlLen = $("#sortable2").length;
   $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        change: function(){
              var afterChangeUlLen = $("#sortable2").length;
              if(beforeChangeUlLen > afterChangeUlLen){
                  /*Add you function after new li is added to ul*/
              }
         }
     }).disableSelection();
 })(jQuery);
```